# Is it possible to access an expect-spawned process from other expect scripts, called in bash

Tags: bash, session, process, telnet, expect

I have an expect script that opens a telnet session and performs the authorization. After the authorization has been performed, I want to be able to call from bash other expect scripts, that perform various actions in the same session.

Is it possible?

Comment: `I want to be able to call from bash other expect scripts` means you want to call other bash script which have expect to telnet and do authorization right?

Comment: I want to keep the authorization and do other actions in other expect scripts.

Comment: ok, so in other script you expect for other thing not for telnet right then it's ok it is possible.

Comment: No, I want to login to telnet in the first expect script and perform other actions with other scripts in the same telnet session after that.

Comment: I think you'll have to make the login script act like a proxy server, and all the subordinate scripts will connect to the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly getting what you want because if you provide some code or script then batter but anyway i just having bash script which only open telnet session which is first part what you want now let me know what next part while gone through script so i can modify my script as you want.

```
#!/bin/bash

testUserAction()
{
     expect<<EOF

     set timeout 200

     spawn telnet $1

     expect "login:"
     send "testuser\r"
     expect "Password"
     send "12345678\r"
      ;;;;;;;;;;;;;#rest of expect which you want

    EOF

}

testUserAction 171.172.12.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible see below example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect

set user "user"
set host "host"
set pass "password"

spawn telnet $host

set timeout 10
expect {
    timeout {
        puts "Unable to connect to $host"
        exit 1
    }

    "login: " {
        send -- "$user\r"
        exp_continue
    }

    "assword: " {
        send -- "$pass\r"
    }
}

#Call the other expect script on host
send -- "./test.exp $user\r"
expect {
    "($user)" {
        puts "OK got it!"
    }
}
```

And then the test.exp script which should be in users home directory on host

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect

set name [lindex $argv 0]

puts "Welcome ($name)"
```

Comment: This sends a command to execute the second expect script on the remote host. I want to execute the second expect script on the same machine that executed the first one. Also, I want expect scripts to be called separately from bash, without one calling another.